# Thinkpad X1 Yoga 1st gen, side volume buttons dead in tablet mode only

Tags: thinkpad

The side volume buttons next to the audio jack on a Thinkpad X1 Yoga 1st gen are working fine when in laptop mode, but stop working in tablet mode. I suppose that's because the whole keyboard/touchpad gets disabled in tablet mode for obvious reasons, but is there a way to make an exception for those side volume buttons so that they always work?

EDIT: Ubuntu 18.04.3 desktop 64 bit.

Please excuse me for failing to include the obvious info.

Comment: run ``sudo xev`` and check if it shows the button clicks

Comment: When in laptop mode - yes, when in tablet mode - no.

Comment: To start with, which version of Linux have you installed  (Ubuntu server, Ubuntu desktop, Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, et al.) , and which release number? Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please do not use Add Comment.